# How to query Postgres' JSON column for specific nested keys

Tags: postgresql, json

I've got this JSON in a Postgres column:

```json
{
   "type":"doc",
   "content":[
      {
         "type":"paragraph",
         "content":[
            {
               "type":"text",
               "text":"Yolo"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"paragraph",
         "content":[
            {
               "type":"attachment",
               "attrs":{
                  "href":"/files/file.zip"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I want to fetch all `content` objects of type `attachment`.

At first, I wanted to get all nested fields, but I don't know how to iterate through all JSON "rows":

```sql
SELECT json_array_elements_text(content->'content'->2->'content')
FROM jsonb_test
```

So how can I replace `2` with a selector (or something link this?) that gets all `content` inside `content`? I could imagine (pseudocode) like `json_array_elements_text(content->'content'->[]->'content')`, but didn't found something like this in the documentation.

Second, I want to just query objects of `"type":"paragraph"`, so I've tried this:

```sql
SELECT json_array_elements_text(content->'content'->2->'content')
FROM jsonb_test
WHERE content->'content'->2->'content'->'type' = 'attachment'
```

But I get this error, which I don't understand.

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = unknown
LINE 3: WHERE content->'content'->2->'content'->'type' = 'attachment...
                                                       ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

At first I thought I have to cast the type like this: `content->'content'->2->'content'->'type'::text`, but then I still get the same error message:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = unknown
LINE 3: ...RE content->'content'->2->'content'->'type'::text = 'attachm...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: `select j from jsonb_test cross join jsonb_path_query(content, '$.content[*].content ? (@.type=="attachment")') as j;` is this what you are looking for? SQL/JSON Path, available in postgresql 12+

Comment: What exactly is the output you are looking for? Please **[edit]** your question and add the desired result

Comment: @Melkij, thanks a lot, this was exactly what I was looking for!